# Can't properly fill area below my function

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I can't figure how to properly fill the area below my function (between f and 0) with TikZ.
Here is my code:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
   axis lines=left,
   scaled ticks=false,
   xticklabel style={
      rotate=0,
      anchor=east,
      /pgf/number format/precision=0,
      /pgf/number format/fixed,
      /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
}, ]
\addplot[red,domain=0:15,samples=201, name path=A] {(25+x*(x-6)*(x-8)*(x-14)/25)*exp(sqrt(1+cos(deg(x^2/10))))};
\addplot[draw=none,domain=0:15,name path=B] {0};     % “fictional” curve
\addplot[thick, color=red, fill=red, fill opacity=0.1] fill between [of=A and B,soft clip={domain=0:15}]; % filling
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

But what I get is this:
[image: unwanted filling]

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: A very warm welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: [Is this what you want?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HrG9J.png)

Comment: This is exactly what I want !

Comment: For filling to the x axis, you can just add `\closedcycle` at the end of the `\addplot` command.

Comment: @Alenanno ^^ You have mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a name path for the X axis (or the Y), so no need for an extra plot command. Also, removing the soft clip fixes the fill.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
   axis lines=left,
   scaled ticks=false,
   xticklabel style={
      rotate=0,
      anchor=north,
      /pgf/number format/precision=0,
      /pgf/number format/fixed,
      /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
}, 
x axis line style={name path=xaxis}
]
\addplot[red,domain=0:15,samples=201, name path=A] {(25+x*(x-6)*(x-8)*(x-14)/25)*exp(sqrt(1+cos(deg(x^2/10))))};
\addplot[thick, color=red, fill=red!50] fill between [of=A and xaxis]; % filling
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @MPikkle You're welcome! :)